# Overriding the default constructor/destructor without implementing them

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I have the following class:

```
//myClass.h

myClass{
    int data;
public:
    myClass();
    void foo1(int);
    void foo2();
    ~myClass();
};

//myClass.cpp

#include"myClass.h"
myClass::foo1(int a){
    data = a ;
}

// main
int main(){
    myClass m;
    m.foo1(10);
}
```

Why is it that we can have a non implemented function (i.e., function prototype in header, but no definition in .cpp file), but not a non-implemented default constructor or destructor?

If I leave the default constructor/destructor unimplemented (like in the example above), why do i get a compiler error?

I'm seeing an `undefined reference to myClass::myClass()` when i don't implement the constructor, and an `undefined reference to vtable for myClass`, when i don't implement the destructor. However, if i implement both of these (even with an empty block `{}`), and leave a *method* (ex. `foo2()`) unimplemented, the compiler doesn't complain.

Aren't constructors/destructors essentially just methods in a class? If so, why can I have an undefined method `foo2()`, but not undefined constructors or destructors?

If someone could help me understand this (and not just " because that's just the way it is" :), that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it that we can have a non implemented function (i.e., function
>   prototype in header, but no definition in .cpp file), but not a
>   non-implemented default constructor or destructor?

Your assertion is false.  You *can* have a non-implemented default constructor.  In fact, this is one way to ensure that your class is never implicitly constructed.

> If I leave the default constructor/destructor unimplemented (like in
>   the example above), why do i get a compiler error?

Because you are using it somewhere in your code.  Re-read your compiler error.  It is likely telling you exactly where.

And here it is:

```
int main(){
myClass m;
m.foo1(10);
```

The line `myClass m;` instantiates `myClass`, using the default constructor.

You may declare but not implement a default constructor and compile clean if you do not use the defaul constructor.  Consider:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo (int x) {}
    Foo();
};

int main()
{
    Foo f (1);
}
```

Here there is a declaration for `Foo()`, but no implementation.  The code compiles with no compiler or linker errors.  However, this code will not compile clean:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f;
}
```

The latter example is what you were trying to do, here:

```
myClass m;
```

Comment: What do _you_ mean by non implemented default constructor? I meant one with just a prototype, and no definition (i.e., not even an empty code block.). I understand from the answers above that that a non-implemented constructor throws a linker error, but an empty default constructor can be useful (ex., in some designs of singleton classes), like you say. Hope we're on the same page - if not, please let me know what I've misunderstood. Thanks.

Comment: @srihari: I meant exactly what you meant.  An unimplemented default constructor will only generate a linker error if you try to use it.  If you do not try to use the default constructor, you will compile clean.

Comment: If you declare a default constructor `myClass()` but do not implement it either inline (meaning you declared it within your class declaration as `myClass() {}`) or in an implementation file (meaning you will have a `myClass::myClass() {}` somewhere) and then try to instantiate an object of `myClass` (e.g. `myClass a`), the default constructor (the one that takes no arguments) is not found by the linker, so it will give you an error.

Comment: @John Dibling: I see. So as long as I _never_ create an object of this class, I will not see any issues (compiler or linker). The problem, like you said, only occurs in `myClass m`. Got it.

Comment: @ZacHowland:  True, but that wasn't what I understood the question to really be.  I understood the question to be: "Why can you have unimplemented methods but not unimplemented default constructors?"  The answer to that is, "You can."  It just so happens that OP's example code wouldn't compile because he was trying to *use* the unimplemented default constructor.

Comment: @srihari:  Not quite.  So long as you never create an object of that class *using the default constructor* you will not see any issues.  You can still use other constructors.  See my example.

Comment: @JohnDibling: perfect, now i understand what you meant. thanks for the Detailed explanation :)

Comment: @JohnDibling Agreed.  I was writing up my comment at the same time and didn't see you had said basically the same thing, yet. :)

Answer (score 4):

> If so, why can I have an undefined method `foo2()`, but not undefined constructors or destructors?

Because you are using the constructor and destructor, and not using `foo2()`. Add a call to it, and you'll get a link-time error.

Comment: I did, and you're right, i see the "undefined reference" error. So this means even if I have no code in the contstructor/destructor/function implementation, ex. `{}` , it's okay, but leaving it as a prototype isn't? Why so? Aren't the two essentially the same?

Comment: @srihari:  If an answer here was helpful, please consider upvoting it.  Also if an answer here *answered* your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling : Tried to. Apparently there's a wait time of a few minutes before i can do this.

Comment: @srihari:  Ah, ok.  Didn't mean to pester.  Just that sometimes new posters don't quite get how things work here.  You obviously get it.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Lol, my double digit reputation gave me away :P

Answer (score 1):

The compiler only cares about the code you have declared (which is what your class declarations do).  If you declare your constructor, it assumes that you have implemented it somewhere.  The linker will attempt to find that implementation when you use it.  For a constructor/destructor, you use it when you attempt to create an instance of the class.  If they don't exist, you will get a linker error.  If you do not use `foo2()`, and you do not implement, the linker doesn't need to find it, so it will not try to.  Thus, you get no linker error and your code will be successfully compiled and linked into the executable.

Comment: Two nits: first, if you don't provide an implementation, formally, it is undefined behavior (although in practice, I don't know of an implementation where you won't get an error from the linker).  And second, it _is_ possible to create an instance of the class if there is no destructor: `new MyClass`.  (But you still need the constructor.)

Comment: @JamesKanze if you declare a destructor and do not implement it, you will get a linker error when you attempt to destroy an instance of `MyClass` on the heap.  And it isn't really "undefined behavior" as it is not dealing with the language directly, but with the compilation process (which, if you wanted to get technical, is completely undefined behavior as it is not something the standard addresses at all).

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Re first nit -- Do you mean to say "if you don't provide an implementation *but try to use it* [...]"?  Or are you saying an unimplemented (but declared) default constructor results in UB *even if you don't use it*?

Comment: @ZacHowland If you call `delete p`, and `p` has type `MyClass*`, you will get an error if you fail to define the destructor.  But if you call `new MyClass`, you won't.  It's only when you try to delete it that you have a problem; if you never delete it, then you don't need to define the destructor.

Comment: @ZacHowland With regards to undefined behavior: "Every program
shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no
diagnostic required." (§3.2/3) I don't know of any compiler
which doesn't give an error if the definition is missing, but
according to the standard, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnDibling It is only undefined behavior if the function is part of an expression which is "potentially evaluated".  (The standard only speaks of expressions here, but I think it is clear that the intent, at least, includes the constructor calls which occur as part of variable initialization.)

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Got it.  You made me a little nervous, there.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, if you create a memory leak, you can get away with it.  There are a lot of things you can get away with doing if you use horrible coding practices ;)

Comment: @ZacHowland First, if you only do it once, it's not a memory leak.  Second, there are specific cases where you do this intentionally (in a singleton, for example).  And third, we are talking about what is and is not required by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that we can have a non implemented function (i.e., function prototype in header, but no definition in .cpp file), but not a non-implemented default constructor or destructor?

Any function that's used must be defined. Most functions can be left undefined if they're not used.

> If I leave the default constructor/destructor unimplemented (like in the example above), why do i get a compiler error?

Because your program creates and destroys an instance of your class, which uses the constructor and destructor; since they're used, they must be defined. You've declared them, so they won't be defined implicitly; therefore, you must define them yourself.

> I'm seeing an undefined reference to myClass::myClass() when i don't implement the constructor;

That's because the constructor is used to create the object.

> and an undefined reference to `vtable` for myClass, when i don't implement the destructor.

That's because this compiler generates the `vtable` in the same translation unit as the destructor (if it's neither implicit nor inline). If you don't declare the destructor but don't define it, you won't get the `vtable` either.

> However, if i implement both of these (even with an empty block {}), and leave a method (ex. foo2()) unimplemented, the compiler doesn't complain.

That's because you don't use the function. If you were to call it, then you'd get an error.

> Aren't constructors/destructors essentially just methods in a class?

More or less, yes; but they are special in various ways. The language specification describes them as "special member functions", and has a whole chapter describing their properties.

> If so, why can I have an undefined method `foo2()`, but not undefined constructors or destructors?

To reiterate: you must define anything you use. Constructors and destructors are used if you instantiate the class.